# Difference between TCustomForm.SetFocusedControl and TWinControl.SetFocus

Tags: delphi

I need to set focus on a `TEdit` control. Usually, I use `TWinControl.SetFocus` after checking if the control can be focused. Recently, I noticed that `TCustomForm` class provides `SetFocusedControl` function.

In which cases would be better to use `TCustomForm.SetFocusedControl` instead of `TWinControl.SetFocus` to set the focus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SetFocusedControl` is used in various places by the VCL framework in response to windows messages relating to focus changes. For instance, if you call `SetFocus` on a control, then `SetFocusedControl` does get called to update internal state.

Although `SetFocusedControl` is a public method, it is really a framework method, and is intended only to be called from code that implements VCL controls. It is better if you think of it as a private method. It does not call the Windows `SetFocus` function (hence it does not change focus) and only updates internal state to track the focus control.

In your case you have application code, that is using the VCL. You are not writing a VCL control. You should continue to call `SetFocus` in order to effect a change of focus. When you do so the VCL will internally call `SetFocusedControl` for its needs.

> In which cases would be better to use `TCustomForm.SetFocusedControl` instead of `TWinControl.SetFocus` to set the focus?

None.

Comment: I'll go further and claim VCL's own use is even problematic at times. It may lead to a non-focusable control to be identified as the focused control. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328375/grid-scroll-behind-modal-window) is an example.